# GuzzleHttp Client object's is slow and dont know what it is doing

Tags: php, yii2, guzzle

I am calling REST API from server side code with GuzzleHttp library. Whenever I run it from my local machine it is working fine, giving prompt responses. If I run it on a VPS hosted server, it takes a while (ca 30 sec), however it gives the right answer. I tried to debug what it takes so long, but cant understand and debug these lines in the code:
return Promise\promise_for($handler($request, $options));
It is in the guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php file (line 277.)

I am not familiar with HTTP processes that deeply, and I can not figure out what makes the difference. The code is that same in both environments. I use WAMP on my local machine with php version 7.1.9. The VPS hosted environment has Windows Server 2016 and php version of 7.2.14. If I run the REST API from my  VPS server's browser, it is also fast.

Can anyone tell me what happens behind that line of code???

Comment: Can I suggest trying it with an IP address and a host header to see if its a DNS issue.

Comment: I tried, but the result is the same. I guess if it were a DNS issue, then it should be slow from the broser too. Or?

Comment: It would, but that's if you were browsing or doing DNS resolutions on your VPS

Comment: Can only guess, but perhaps your remote machine does not have PHP curl extension installed? Guzzle detects what handlers there are available depending on extensions installed in system, so maybe it is using one of the slower ones, or one that doesn't do multiple requests at the same time that well. You can also try setting debug option for Guzzle and see if anything pops up.

Comment: Yess, the curl extension was not enabled! Thank you ncla!!! Saved a lot of time for me! :)

Comment: @varpet No problem. I submitted an actual answer (I didn't think that was the solution, was just guessing). On Stackoverflow, if you think an answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your remote machine does not have PHP curl extension installed. Guzzle detects what handlers there are available depending on extensions installed in the system, so maybe it is using one of the slower ones, or one that doesn't do multiple requests at the same time that well.